# How to get attachment id as soon as it is uploaded through media uploader in jquery?

Tags: jquery, uploads, javascript, media-library

Using jquery, I am trying to get image attachment id of all images requested to upload through media uploader on post edit page or upload.php.
Here is what I tried but this works after all images are uploaded:

```
if (typeof wp.Uploader !== 'undefined' && typeof wp.Uploader.queue !== 'undefined') {
    wp.Uploader.queue.on('reset', function() { 
        console.log('images uploaded!');
    });
}
```

How can achieve the same?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, you just need to hook into the `add` event instead of the `reset` event. (In case you did not know, these are [standard events provided by Backbone collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog). So familiarizing yourself with that will be helpful when developing things around stuff where WordPress employs Backbone.js.)

So basically you'd modify your code like this:

```
if (typeof wp.Uploader !== 'undefined' && typeof wp.Uploader.queue !== 'undefined') {
    wp.Uploader.queue.on('add', function() { 
        console.log('image uploaded!');
    });
}
```